# В Tkinter в классе меню не запускаются подменю

Tags: python, tkinter

В игровом приложении, написанном с помощью библиотеки Python, удалось отладить весь функционал кроме запуска строчки меню. Она открывается, однако увидеть, что скрывает подменю, не выходит.

С чем это может быть связано?

P.S. Без классов код работает. Привожу его в сокращенном виде - только класс меню

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# class ProgrammMenu(tk.Frame):
class ProgrammMenu():
    def __init__(self, main):
#         tk.Frame.__init__(self, main)
        self.main = main
        
        self.frame_menu = tk.Frame(
            master=self.main, 
            relief=tk.RIDGE, 
            borderwidth=5
        )
        # добавим пункт меню с соответствующими вкладками 
        self.mainmenu = tk.Menu(self.frame_menu) 
        self.main.config(menu=self.mainmenu)
        self.helpmenu = tk.Menu(self.mainmenu, tearoff=0)     
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label='Справка', command=self.edit_click_help, underline=5)
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label='О разработчике', command=self.edit_click_developer, underline=5)
        self.mainmenu.add_cascade(label='О программе',
                     menu=self.helpmenu)
    # определим функции реагирования на нажатие кнопок меню
    def edit_click_help(self):
        self.messagebox.showinfo('Справка', 'Задайте вопрос шару -\nи он ответит. \nОбучите шар, чтобы он стал умнее')  
    def edit_click_developer(self):
        self.messagebox.showinfo('О разработчике', 'Разработчик программы \nВасилий Пупкин')

        self.frame_menu.grid(
            row=0, column=0, 
            padx=5, pady=5
        ) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Магический шар')
    window.resizable(0, 0)
    window.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)

    menu_sphere = ProgrammMenu(window)

    window.update()
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создание подменю корректное, можно весь код?

Comment: Расскажите лучше, что в приведенном вами примере не так. Кроме того, что надо заменить  `self.messagebox` на `messagebox`.

Comment: @С. Ник, благодарю за наводку - все гуд )

Comment: @ganz, вроде, в итоге сей код норм - заработал